# jQuery date format not set in correct format for application

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, asp.net-mvc-4

I have added jQuery datepicker to my MVC4 application so that on click of a text box a calendar control appears and from the selection the date is posted into the textbox in the format MM/DD/YYYY

I want to return this in the format DD/MM/YYYY but have been unable to do so. My code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#expirydate').datepicker()
      .datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
  });
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong here? If I try to post in the format MM/DD/YYYY then my application is throwing in invalid date error

Comment: Did you mean `.datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });`?  You have `.datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });`.

Comment: I'll post the answer again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
.datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

to

```
.datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
```